# Contact Form DB - WordPress plugin exporting to excel is not working

Tags: wordpress, export-to-excel, contact-form-7

I've around 5 forms in my WordPress website. All using Contact Form 7. Also installed the Contact Form DB plugin (contact-form-7-to-database-extension - the plugin is discontinued now). Problem is, I cannot export the data to Excel(.xlsx). Showing an error "File not found" and is redirecting to https://www.example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=cfdb-export&form=Contact+form&enc=xlsx&regionaldelimiter=true

But exporting to "Excel CSV (UTF8-BOM)" is working without any issue.

I've enabled the WordPress debugging options in wp-config, but no errors are logged. If I change the parameter enc=xlsx to enc=csv in the above url, it works.

Comment: You can convert CSV to Excel. The plugin is updated 3years ago, it may conflict with your Wordpress & possibly their isn't any solution.

Comment: Hmm. Probably yes. There is a recent version of the plugin at github. Will give it a shot. Thanks for the reply